# Sounds won't play android

Tags: java, android

Okay, I know that I've not been the best at accept rate...and I will make up for that...that being said.

I have followed a TON of Splash Screen tutorials and THOUGHT that I had something that would work...however, the sound won't work...and whenever I finish I get the error "cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Any suggestions: here is the COMPLETE SplashScreen.java code:

```
 package com.droidnova.android;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.R;


 public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
protected boolean _active = true;
protected int _splashTime = 5000;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    MediaPlayer mpSplash = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.laugh);
    mpSplash.start();

    // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
    Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                    sleep(100);
                    if(_active) {
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent("com.droidnova.android.splashscreen.MyApp"));
                stop();
            }
        }
    };
    splashTread.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        _active = false;
    }
    return true;
     }
}
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE!

Here's the code for the AndroidManifest.xml film:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.droidnova.android"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MyApp">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.droidnova.android.splashscreen.MyApp" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
 </manifest>
```

There is an error on lines 5 and 6: 
Line 5: `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/ app_name').`
Line 6: `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/ app_name').`

Added R.java:

```
 /* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
  *
  * This class was automatically generated by the
  * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
  * should not be modified by hand.
  */

 package com.droidnova.android;

 public final class R {
     public static final class attr {
}
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int icon=0x7f020000;
}
public static final class id {
    public static final int textView1=0x7f050000;
}
public static final class layout {
    public static final int main=0x7f030000;
    public static final int splash=0x7f030001;
}
public static final class string {
    public static final int app_name=0x7f040000;
    public static final int main_screen=0x7f040001;
    public static final int splash_screen=0x7f040002;
}
}
```

Comment: @Femi: 67% isn't really that bad. Sometimes you just don't get a good answer to a question.

Comment: Egor, just added logcat, so it is currently empty.  Sorry :-(

Comment: @Aaron, do you have a String value with the name `app_name` in your strings.xml file? Try replacing `android:label=@string/app_name` with `android:label="Label"`, clean, and rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `import android.R;`.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, however once I removed it...I now get that "raw cannot be resolved or is not a field"  Any more suggestions?

Comment: Delete R.java and regenerate it.

Comment: Deleted...however, not I can't get it back!?!?  HELP!?!?

Comment: Get rid of all the errors in your `xml` files, then Project -> Clean (in Eclipse).

Comment: And...nothing is happening...any other suggestions, Gabriel?

Comment: Right-click on the project, Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties.

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
R cannot be resolved to a variable MyApp.java /SplashScreen/src/com/droidnova/android line 13 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable SplashScreen.java /SplashScreen/src/com/droidnova/android line 19 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable SplashScreen.java /SplashScreen/src/com/droidnova/android line 21 Java Problem

Comment: This might be some sort of a circular reference error. You have errors in your code because you're missing R.java, and you can't regenerate R.java because of the errors. Try commenting out the lines in your code that refer to R.* and see if you can regenerate it then.

Comment: Later edit: I just copy-pasted your code and it works like it should, after I deleted `import R.android`.

Comment: Gabriel; errors are now : In "MyApp.xml" & "SplashScreen.xml" = R cannot be resolved to a variable ==== That's the extent...I corrected the other errors...but it seems that R.java hates me!

Comment: Added R.java to original question...perhaps that will help

Comment: now that I have R.java working...I only get 1 error; on SplashScreen.xml it says that "raw cannot be resolved or is not a field" WTF?

Comment: Delete `laugh` file from the `raw` folder and add it back again (make sure it has an extension, or the `MediaPlayer` will crash).

Comment: I deleted it and replaced it.  Still nothing.  It still continues to say "raw cannot be rendered or is not a field"...I simply created the raw subfolder in the res folder...was there another way to go about that?

Comment: All right, let's try it from the beginning. Create a new project, create the `raw` folder, put `laugh.wav` inside it and replace the code with the one you posted in the beginning, minus the `import android.R` part. When I did this, everything compiled and worked, except the (expected) runtime crash at `startActivity(new Intent("com.droidnova.android.splashscreen.MyApp"));`. See what happens.

Comment: it's fixed...didn't need to start over...something you said did it...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a file named "laugh" in the `res/raw` folder.

Answer (score 1):

You should go ahead and include the actual build errors, but I suspect that you changed the class package but not the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml file. What is the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

EDIT: that package name should be exactly the same as the class package (`com.droidnova.android`) or you'll get build-time resolution errors.

Comment: It is the same...but just to show: 

Here are the errors: 1. raw cannot be resolved or is not a field.  2. Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output/Android Packaging Problem.  3. Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output/Android ADT Problem.

Comment: Yeah, that's why it can't be resolved, because `aapt` fails. Open all your XML files and look for the errors that are causing the failure.

Comment: There are no errors in ANY of my XML files...any other suggestions?

Comment: If you're getting `unparsed aapt errors` then either you have found a bug in `aapt` (possible) or there is an error in one of your XML files or in your AndroidManifest.xml file (more likely).

Comment: You clearly need to add the `app_name` string to your `strings.xml` file.

Comment: app_name is in there, Femi...I double checked!

Comment: Well, `aapt` doesn't think so. And `aapt` is never wrong.  You may have a space in front of it somehow (the error seems to show an extra space as in `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/ app_name').`: notice the space between / and `app_name`?). Check that there are no spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have automatic building on in Eclipse, and deleting R.java and rebuilding didn't fix your problem, one thing I can think of causing this issue would be if you tried to run the app while an XML document was open. Check for any extra `*.out.xml` files in your resources (e.g. `main.out.xml`). If you find any of these, delete them, clean your project (Project > Clean...) and see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: Nothing...still...I have NO XML files other than the AndroidManifest.xml...when I deleted that one, it said couldn't repair w/o it.

Comment: You have no XML files at all? You must have a splash.xml, and most likely a main.xml. (under res/layout).

Comment: I did, but someone else told me to get rid of them all...then rebuild...I"M A n00b at this shit, so, bear with me.

Comment: I restored them from history...R.java has been regen-ed...and still get the same damn errors

Comment: "I did, but someone else told me to get rid of them all" - I only said to get rid of the errors in the xml files.

Comment: whoops...I misunderstood...and that wasn't supposed to be a rude comment, I just didn't know who said it...sorry

Comment: No problems, you have other things to worry about now :)

Comment: Something I did, relating to the final thing that Gabriel said made the errors go away...so, I thank each and everyone of you for helping out, because I'm sure, along the way, everything that you said, helped me.  Thanks again!

P.s.-that was just the spalsh screen!